# How to remove duplicates from two different lists?

Tags: java, list, compare

I have two lists in java where I need to remove duplicates. One list contains a class (UrlInfo) with three fields, the other contains a list of strings. I need to compare the list of strings with a field from the class and remove duplicates from the list containing the class.

Here is what I have right now.

```
String urlString;
for (UrlInfo url : urlClass) {
  urlString = url.getUrl();
  for (int i = 0; i < storedUrlList.size(); i++) {
    if (urlString.equals(storedUrlList.get(i))) {
      urlClass.remove(url);
    }
  }
}
```

This is extremely slow for me. The lists that I will be working with will contain upwards of 100,000 elements.

Comment: Switch to `HashSet` it will add space - but there is tradeoff

Answer (score 0):

I'd first iterate the List checking if they match the List, if so, I'd store them in a List and then call removeAll() like this:

```
List<String> toBeComparedWith ...
List<UrlInfo> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
for (UrlInfo uInfo : urlClass){
    if (toBeComparedWith.contains(uInfo.getUrl()){
        toBeRemoved.add(uInfo);
    }
}

urlClass.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the list to be compared `storedUrlList` is a list of strings, so you can use the method `List#contains(Object)` to achieve the comparison, and remove the elements from your original list `urlClasses`.

In Java 7:

```
ListIterator<UrlClass> iterator = urlClasses.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  UrlClass u = iterator.next();
  if (storedUrlList.contains(u.getUrl())) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

In Java 8:

```
urlClasses.removeIf(u -> storedUrlList.contains(u.getUrl()));
```